# Laravel fortify подмена шаблона подтверждения почты

Tags: laravel, sendmail, laravel-fortify

Как подменить дефолтный шаблон письма подтверждения почты?
Прошерстил всю документацию `laravel fortify`, но так и не нашел как это сделать.

Может, кто-то сможет подсказать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы экспортировать компоненты, используйте vendor:publish команду Artisan для публикации laravel-mailтега актива:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Эта команда опубликует почтовые компоненты Markdown в resources/views/vendor/mailкаталоге. Почтовый каталог будет содержать html и текстовый каталог, каждый из которых содержит соответствующие представления каждого доступного компонента. Вы можете настроить эти компоненты по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: да не за что .)